# Video Upload API only works with 1 file type?

Tags: c#, api, rest

I have a script that uploads a video to an **API** I built, and after it processes on the **API** side, a *text* file is returned to the client. The strange thing is, this only works with one type of file, a `.QT` file extension. Any other video type I try to send sends and empty video. I have tried `.mov`, `.mp4`, and `.qt` and only the `.qt` uploads properly. I'll post my code below. Would anyone know what cause only the one file type to work? Nothing on the **API** side singles out the *qt* file. I believe this is an issue with this script.

```cs
public async void Function() { 

        Debug.Log("works1");
        string filePath = "IMG_0491.mov";
        //string filePath = ProcessMode.theFilePath; 
        var client = new HttpClient();
        

        using (var multipartFormContent = new MultipartFormDataContent()) {
            //Add the file
            Debug.Log("works2");
            

            var fileStreamContent = new StreamContent(File.OpenRead(filePath));

            Debug.Log("works3");

            fileStreamContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("video/mov");
            multipartFormContent.Add(fileStreamContent, name: "file", fileName: filePath); //Originally Actual "Name`

            //Send it
            var response = await client.PostAsync("http://127.0.0.1:5000/", multipartFormContent); //Enter IP and Port of API when set up
            Debug.Log("works4");

            //Ensure it was successful.
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            //Grab the animation data from the content.
            var animation_data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            Debug.Log(animation_data);
            //Save to file.
            //File.WriteAllTextAsync("AnimationFile.txt", animation_data);
            await File.WriteAllTextAsync("AnimationFile.txt", animation_data);
            Debug.Log("works5");
        }
```

Comment: All I see is c# code.  Can you explain how the python tag and opencv tag is relevant? Otherwise, please remove them.

Comment: Also, what does the code look like of the `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` post endpoint? I assume you also have control of that, since that is a local host URL

Comment: Here is my Pythin API code

Comment: from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for, send_from_directory, request
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import cv2
from cvzone.PoseModule import PoseDetector

UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'uploads'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'3gp', 'mov', 'qt', 'avi', 'wmv', 'mp4'} 

app = Flask(__name__)

Comment: app.config["DEBUG"] = True
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1000 * 1000 # Limit upload size to 16 megabytes per file.

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/uploads/<name>')
def download_file(name):
    return send_from_directory(app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"], name)

Comment: @app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            return redirect(request.url,400, "File part not found in request.")
        file = request.files['file']
        print("Debug 1")
        if file.filename == '':
            return redirect(request.url,400, "Filename is empty.")

Comment: if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            print("Debug 2")
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            cap = cv2.VideoCapture(filename)
            detector = PoseDetector()
            posList = []
            while True:
                print("Debug 3")
                success, img = cap.read()

Comment: if img is None:
                        break
                img = detector.findPose(img)
                lmList, bboxInfo = detector.findPosition(img)
                if bboxInfo:
                    print("Debug 4")
                    lmString = ''
                    for lm in lmList:
                        lmString += f'{lm[1]},{img.shape[0] - lm[2]},{lm[3]},'
                    posList.append(lmString)
            # file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)) Don't need to save the file

Comment: with open("uploads/AnimationFile.txt", 'w') as f:
                f.writelines(["%s\n" % item for item in posList])
                print("Debug 5")
            print("Debug 6")
            return redirect(url_for('download_file', name="AnimationFile.txt"))
    return '''<h1>Test Api!</h1>'''

app.run()

Comment: I'm sorry, I am very new to Stack Overflow and do not know how to add a longer or better-formatted comment

Comment: You can edit that python code into your post using this link https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73759862/edit